# Documentation about Visual Studio Express 2012, xaml objects

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I searched on Google all the day, but i didn't find a documentation containing a list of all objects to create a visual app in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows8. I'm in "MainPage.xaml", and I don't know "Grid" "Button" "TextBlock" controls and their properties... Where can I find them?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is location [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465351.aspx).  Additionally, all the controls should be listed in the toolbox view.  It typically is located on the left side of the window.